# ElasticSearch: min_doc_count on lower/lowest level nested aggregation

Tags: elasticsearch

I have this query with some nested aggregations

```
{
   "aggs": {
      "by_date": {
         "date_histogram": {
            "field": "timestamp",
            "interval": "day"
         },
         "aggs": {
            "new_users": {
               "filter": {
                  "query": {
                     "match": {
                        "action": "USER_ADD"
                     }
                  }
               },
               "aggs": {
                  "unique_users": {
                     "cardinality": {
                        "field": "user"
                     }
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   },
   "size": 0
}
```

It yields results that look like this

```
"aggregations": {
      "by_date": {
         "buckets": [
            {
               "key_as_string": "1970-01-07T00:00:00.000Z",
               "key": 518400000,
               "doc_count": 210,
               "new_users": {
                  "doc_count": 0,
                  "unique_users": {
                     "value": 0
                  }
               }
            },
            {
               "key_as_string": "1970-01-09T00:00:00.000Z",
               "key": 691200000,
               "doc_count": 6,
               "new_users": {
                  "doc_count": 0,
                  "unique_users": {
                     "value": 0
                  }
               }
            },
       ......
```

What I want to happen is apply min_doc_count on the most nested sub-aggregation such that I don't see zero values for "unique_users" (in this case) returned.

The issue is that min_doc_count can't be applied to my query other than the date_histogram at the top level.

Does the ES query language support something like this?  Any know workarounds?

Thanks,
George

Answer (score 0):

As per ElasticSearch Documentation min_doc_count can used with any aggregation including histogram

for example

```
{
    "aggs" : {
        "tags" : {
            "terms" : {
                "field" : "tag"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

the above query is not date_histogram still you can apply the min_doc_count

```
{
    "aggs" : {
        "tags" : {
            "terms" : {
                "field" : "tag",
                "min_doc_count" : 1
            }
        }
    }
}
```

only thing is min_doc_count can be applied to any aggregation